# Is it possible to make redis strongly consistent?

Tags: redis, replication, consistency, redis-cluster

The https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial states that redis cluster is not strongly consistent. The reasoning it states even if WAIT is enabled is:

- The node to which the update wasn't synced becomes master
- After the partition and before the node timeout master in minority partition keeps receiving updates.

What if for a key k we find the master node M and the replicas r1,r2....rn using

```
CLUSTER SLAVES node-id
```

. And execute

```
WAIT N
```

and only proceed with the transaction if it return N? Wouldn't that always ensure that the data is perfectly synced before executing transaction. Wouldn't that ensure strong consistency ?

Comment: Did yo check RedisRaft? https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisraft

Comment: Thanks Guy for the link. Looks promising. Although this question is more from a theoretical standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

NO, it still CANNOT guarantee.

Although `WAIT` returns N, which means all replicas have acknowledge the writes **in memory**, these nodes might fail before these writes operation are written to disk.

Comment: Why are we talking about disk? Redis is supposed to be in-memory. Persistence is more of a backup option. No reads will happen on disk.